# Traverse list and create records based on date

Tags: c#

I have a list of Data, each of which has 3 datetime property. I need to split the list based on the `fromDate` and `toDate` for a given `endDate`. Is there a way that I can split my main list into sublists so that I have all data in the list as of `endDate` value?

Basic idea is to get revenue at the end of a period can be quarterly, monthly or annually. and based on the revenue for how many months, I have to allocate the revenue for each month.

> revenue for month = revenue for period * days in month/days in period

I have currently extracted a set of Data with the input dataset using linq to sql.

```
var result = (from c in context.BillingRevenues where c.HoldingDate >= firstDayOfTheYear && c.HoldingDate <= endDate && c.RecordType.Equals("I")
                                    join s in seedAccountNumbers
                                    on c.AccountNumber equals s
                             select c).ToList();
                    return result;
```

I want to use this result set and then get the expected output.

my DataSet

```
endDate  fromDate  toDate  Amount HoldingDate
3/31/18  1/1/18    2/28/18 1000
3/31/18  1/1/18    3/31/18 1000
3/31/18  1/1/18    1/31/18 1000
```

result DataSet

```
endDate  fromDate  toDate  HoldingDate Amount
3/31/18  1/1/18    2/28/18 1/31/18     1000/59(days)*31(days)
3/31/18  1/1/18    2/28/18 2/28/18     1000/59(days)*28(days)
3/31/18  1/1/18    3/31/18 1/31/18     1000/90(days)*31(days)
3/31/18  1/1/18    3/31/18 2/28/18     1000/90(days)*28(days)
3/31/18  1/1/18    3/31/18 3/31/18     1000/90(days)*31(days)
3/31/18  1/1/18    1/31/18 1/31/18     1000/31(days)*31(days)
```

Comment: Where did `HoldingDate` come from? Your examples are very unclear.

Comment: I agree with @NetMage, no idea what you are looking for

Comment: Holding Date is an extra field in the the DataSet, that should be populated with the month end date from the combination of "fromDate" and "toDate". for example, for the first record 2 monthend entries are created based on incoming data